# How can I add additional features to my User class

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, dependencies, asp.net-identity

I am working on an Online shopping project. I used JWT for authentication. My User.cs class is:

```
namespace Core.Entities.Concrete
{
    public class User:  IEntity 
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// A person can have multiple Orders
        /// </summary>
        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; } //*Could not be found Error*
        public User() => Orders = new List<Order>(); //*Could not be found Error*
    }
}
```

I want to add Orders feature to my User class, a customer can order products. But Usre.cs class is in Core layer which hasn't dependency to  Entities layer(Order class inside) How can I solve this issue?

I shouldn't give Core layer reference to Entities Layer.

[image: Laysers]

Comment: Move Order to Core? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider separating `Order` and `User` by using dependency injection.

For example we could create an interface called `IOrder` that defines the properties and methods that `Order.cs` has, and the required methods and properties `User` should be able to access.

Then we can inject that dependency into the UI layer.

```cs
services.AddTransient<IOrder,Entities.Order>();
```

Then we can inject that dependency in the user class through it's constructor such as:

```cs
public class User : IEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// A person can have multiple Orders
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<IOrder> Orders { get; set; }

    public User(List<IOrder> Orders) // <-- automatically injected with most DI setups
    {
        this.Orders = Orders;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
For more resources on what *dependency injection* is, and how to use it check out these resources. [This one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0) covers dependency injection ins ASP.NET in general, and [this one](https://entityframeworkcore.com/articles/carloscds-ef-core-dependency-injection) covers dependency injection specifically in Entity-Framework, the thing you tagged as using using.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for the response. I have a question but firstly I want to explain what I understood from your comment: I create IOrder.cs in Core layer, then I make a dependency injection with Order class from Entities layer. 
After that, I create constructor and give IOrder instead of Order.cs.
In this scenario, All of the Users will access the all orders,right?

Comment: When you inject the dependency through the constructor you create a new object of the type that you provide. So User(List<IOrder> Orders) will create a new `List<T>` where T is whatever you injected `IOrder` to be. So in the above example we injected `Entities.Order` so in the constructor it would actually be giving us a List<Entities.Order> instead of List<IOrder>, and we store it in the `ICollection<IOrder>` property.

Comment: Checkout [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0) it has a lot of information on how it works.

Comment: Just personal coding preference, there's nothing stopping you from coding it like `public User(List<IOrder> orders) => Orders = orders;`

Comment: Here's an additional resource that might help you better understand checkout this [tutorial on dependency injection in EF works](https://entityframeworkcore.com/articles/carloscds-ef-core-dependency-injection)